# jquery doesnt work on my browser thought the same code works on jsfiddle tried all the necessary tags along with noconflict tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#boxx').keyup(function(e) {
      var txtVal = $(this).val();
        $('#boxx1').val(txtVal);
    });
    $('#boxx1').keyup(function(e) {
        var txtVal = $(this).val();
        $('#boxx').val(txtVal);
    });
});
   </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" value="" id="boxx"/>
  <input type="text" value="" id="boxx1"/>
  <div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is all the code there is but it doesnt seem to work but it works fine on jsfiddle
please help me im new to jquery

Comment: i think you miss something in the src of the script: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: any error in console ? like `$` not defined etc ??

Comment: Your script imports should be at the bottom of your document, right before the closing body tag - especially with jQuery. Further, your script should be at the bottom of the page as well. Never put JS at the top of the page as it can prevent the page from loading if something goes wrong .

Finally, I recommend using a newer version of jQuery - like v3.3.1

Comment: nope removed all the errors from console

Comment: It works fine for me. Although you have $('#boxx11') instead of $('boxx1') in one of your event listeners.

Comment: thats just a typing mistake dan raps

Comment: @warlordofhogwarts don't remove them. check and post with your question

Comment: Are you running it off the file system when you run it locally and not a local server? If yes, it is the // for the script tags trying to pull it from your computer, not the web. If yes, add http:// instead of just //

Comment: @Korgrue That would make difference since it is using document ready for the bindings.

Comment: now it works ,i put the 3.3.1 version still wont work but when i removed the type part from the script tag containing the jquery function it started working.Strange

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-type advocates not setting the type on a <script> that is a javascript script, fyi @warlordofhogwarts  *Classic scripts are affected by the async and defer attributes, but only when the src attribute is set. Authors should omit the type attribute instead of redundantly setting it.*

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the explanation. I will delete my comment